# Proper updating of an NSManagedObject's relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, nsmanagedobject

I'd like to have a clear understanding of what happens when I do for illustration :

```
Book *newBook = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
// setting book's attributes
Person *peter = [Person queryAndReturnBookCollectionWithName:@"Peter Parker"]; // returns already recorded collection with an already set "favorite book" relationship
peter.favoriteBook = newBook;
```

My guess is that the previously recorded instance of Book in peter.favoriteBook isn't deleted but stays stored am I right ?
So should I manually check if it exists and delete it before setting the new value or is there some more cleaner way to do so ?

Comment: When you create an instance of book (say book1), like you do, an object is created in the database (assuming you save sometime). When you assign this object to a relationship like peter.favouriteBook=book1 then you are just establishing a relationship.  If you now create another book (say book2) and assign the same relationship to book2 (peter.favouriteBook=book2) than the only thing changing is the relationship. Both book1 and book2 still exist in the Book table.  My guess is you wouldn't want to delete book1 because it may well be someone else's favouriteBook!

Comment: On Book you might consider having a To-Many relationship called Book.favouredBy being the inverse of the Person.favoriteBook. The book1.favouredBy would return a NSSet of all the people whose favourite book is book1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous value of favoriteBook is not deleted, but it is no longer pointed to by that object for this relationship. So, peter's previous favoriteBook will still exist in core data, but peter.favoriteBook will return the new value assigned to it.

Comment: Just as I thought, thank you. too bad Xcode doesn't include a core data explorer

Comment: But what about the reverse relationship, does the instance of Book that is no longer pointed by peter.favourite books still points to peter ?

Comment: no, once the relationship is broken, neither objects will point to each other. Core data is aware of the inverse relationship and updates it accordingly